# Structs and arrays challenge in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am trying to solve this challenge:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/structuring-the-document/problem

Basically I have been given a locked stub of code with structs in it and I am supposed to parse a given text. This is an abridged version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define MAX_CHARACTERS 1005
#define MAX_PARAGRAPHS 5

#include <ctype.h>

struct word {
    char* data;
};

struct sentence {
    struct word* data;
    int word_count;//denotes number of words in a sentence
};

struct paragraph {
    struct sentence* data  ;
    int sentence_count;//denotes number of sentences in a paragraph
};

struct document {
    struct paragraph* data;
    int paragraph_count;//denotes number of paragraphs in a document
};

struct document get_document(char* text) {
    int spaces = 0, periods = 0, newlines = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) 
        if(text[i] == ' ')
            spaces++;
        else if(text[i] == '.')
            periods++;
        else if(text[i] == '\n')
            newlines++;


    struct document doc;
    doc.paragraph_count = newlines + 1;
    doc.data = malloc((newlines + 1) * sizeof(struct paragraph));

    struct paragraph para[doc.paragraph_count];
    for(int i = 0; i < doc.paragraph_count; i++) {
        para[i].sentence_count = periods + 1;
        para[i].data = malloc((periods + 1) * sizeof(struct sentence));
    }

    struct sentence sen[para[0].sentence_count];
    for(int i = 0; i < para[0].sentence_count; i++) {
        sen[i].word_count = spaces + 1;
        sen[i].data = malloc((spaces + 1) * sizeof(struct word));
    }

    struct word word[spaces + periods + 1];

    int start = 0, k = 0, wordsub = 0, sensub = 0, parasub = 0, docsub = 0, wordno = 0, parano = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
        if(text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == '.') {
            word[wordsub].data = malloc((i - start) * sizeof(char) + 1);
            for(int j = start; j < i; j++)
                word[wordsub].data[k++] = text[j];
            word[wordsub].data[k++] = '\0';

            k = 0;

            if(i < strlen(text) - 1 && text[i + 1] == '\n')
                start = i + 2;
            else 
                start = i + 1;

            if(text[i] == ' ') {
                sen[sensub].data[wordno++] = word[wordsub++]; //wordno can be 0 or 1
            }
            if(i != strlen(text) && isalpha(text[i + 1]) && text[i] == '.') {
                sen[sensub].data[wordno++] = word[wordsub++];
                wordno = 0;
                para[parasub].data[parano++] = sen[sensub++];


            }
            if((i != strlen(text) && text[i + 1] == '\n') || i + 1 == strlen(text)) {
                sen[sensub++].data[wordno++] = word[wordsub];
                wordno = 0;

                parano = 0;
                para[parasub].data[parano++] = sen[sensub];

                doc.data[docsub++] = para[parasub++];


            }

        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", para[0].data[0].data[0].data);// should print "hello"
    return doc;
}

int main() {
    struct document doc;
    char * text = "hello world.\nhi.bye.\nwow.";
    doc = get_document(text);
    printf("%s\n", doc.data[0].data[0].data[0].data);//should also print "hello"
}
```

The problem is the print statements are not printing "hello". Also if I change the indices in the print statements I get a segmentation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
word[wordsub].data[k++] = text[j];
```

you are accessing ***data*** member out of allocated memory.

Comment: Sorry, edited that. Now it prints "hi" but that is still not the correct output though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement specifies that there are never two terminators after a word. There should also be one word at least.

So, the test phrase

```
"hello world.\nhi.bye.\nwow."
```

does not fit, but

```
"hello world\nhi.bye\nwow"
```

fits and you will have "hello" printed.

Besides, your algorithm is very complex while the code could be simpler. It was fun to try and I did it.

First, let's use some `typedef` to write less text!

```
typedef struct word {
    char* data;
} W;

typedef struct sentence {
    W* data;
    int word_count;//denotes number of words in a sentence
} S;

typedef struct paragraph {
    S* data  ;
    int sentence_count;//denotes number of sentences in a paragraph
} P;

typedef struct document {
    P* data;
    int paragraph_count;//denotes number of paragraphs in a document
} DOC;
```

Then the function itself. The logic is simple, do all of the following for each char of `text` in sequence

- in case we have any separator (`' '`, `'.'` or `'\n'`) record the word
- in case we have a separator (`'.'` or `'\n'`) record the sentence
- in case we have a separator (`'\n'`) record a paragraph

The end of the string counts as the end of a paragraph.

Code

```
struct document get_document(char* text) {
     DOC doc = { NULL, 0 }; // you're the doc, doc
     P parr  = { NULL, 0 };
     S sarr  = { NULL, 0 };

     int wpos=0;

     for(int i=0, l=strlen(text) ; i<=l ; i++) { // <= length! (to deal with \0)
          char c = text[i];
          if ( ! c) c = '\n'; // End of string simulates end of paragraph

          if (c == '\n' || c == '.' || c == ' ') {
                // End of word, add it to sentence
                W word;
                word.data = malloc(i - wpos + 1);          // +1 for '\0'
                strncpy(word.data, text + wpos, i - wpos); // Copy only the word
                word.data[i - wpos] = 0;                   // 0 terminate it
                sarr.data = realloc(sarr.data, sizeof(W) * (sarr.word_count+1));
                sarr.data[ sarr.word_count++ ] = word;
                wpos = i+1;

                if (c == '\n' || c == '.') {
                     // End of sentence, add it to paragraph
                     parr.data = realloc(parr.data, sizeof(S) * (parr.sentence_count+1));
                     parr.data[ parr.sentence_count++ ] = sarr;
                     sarr.data = NULL;    // clear sentences
                     sarr.word_count = 0;
                }

                if (c == '\n') {
                     // End of paragraph, add it to doc
                     doc.data = realloc(doc.data, sizeof(P) * (doc.paragraph_count+1));
                     doc.data[ doc.paragraph_count++ ] = parr;
                     parr.data = NULL;     // clear paragraphs
                     parr.sentence_count = 0;
                }
          }
     }

    return doc;
}
```

Finally, to see if that's working, print all members (using a compliant text!)

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    DOC doc;
    char * text = "hello world\nhi.bye\nwow";

    doc = get_document(text);

    for(int i=0 ; i<doc.paragraph_count ; i++) {
          printf("Para %d / %d\n", i, doc.paragraph_count-1);
          P para = doc.data[i];
          for(int j=0 ; j<para.sentence_count ; j++) {
                printf("Sent %d / %d\n", j, para.sentence_count-1);
                S sent = para.data[j];
                for(int k=0 ; k<sent.word_count ; k++) {
                     W word = sent.data[k];
                     printf("Word %d / %d: %s\n", k, sent.word_count-1, word.data);
                }
          }
     }

     return 0;
}
```

We could add a bit of code to avoid the processing of two separators (like a trailing `'\n'`, or `' .'`